# Skin effect at high voltage

Tags: high-frequency, tesla-coil, shock, skin-effect

I recently made a slayer exciter circuit in order to determine the resonant frequency of my secondary coil of my yet to build SSTC.

When running the slayer exciter at 40V DC the circuit consumes something like 18W of power. I see a small amount of coronal discharge at end of the secondary coil. The oscillation frequency at the base of the transistor is around 550kHz.

When I touched the corona I got shocked, which was unexpected as the skin effect should have come into play at such high frequencies. What is happening here and why am I getting shocked?

Specs:

- Secondary: 1600 turns of 32 gauge copper wire wound around a 4 inch PVC pipe
- Primary: 3 turns of 16 gauge wire
- Transistor used: D4205d NPN fast switching transistor

Comment: Maybe more of a burning sensation rather than a shock?

Comment: Nah it's an actual shock, the weird thing is my first transistor when it was working used to create arc which used to burn my skin, but now this transistor oscillating at the exact same frequency produces arcs which shock me. Its kinda weird

Comment: Skin effect at TC frequencies only applies to metals, not to human tissue. (See calculation Skin Depth of salt water, versus Skin Depth of copper.  Humans have even higher resistivity than ocean water!  IIRC, skin depth of people is > 50cm at 200KHz.)  Also, to eliminate thermal skin-burns,  hold a metal object such as a key or coin in your fingers, and jump the arc to the metal surface.  If you feel nothing, then the pain of the "shock" had been entirely from tiny skin burns via the hot arc-plasma, not from direct nerve stimulation of deeper tissues.

Comment: can this make hair turn grey?